# How can I do this using querydsl?

Tags: java, sql, querydsl

I have this part of my query which I'm transforming into querydsl and I would like to know if there's a way to achieve this transformation

```
Where...
...
and ce.id || ce.is_open not in (select fut_client.client_id || fut_client.is_available from future_client fut_client)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You're using `querydsl-sql`
- In the sql provided `||` is concatenation
- `id` and `client_id` are numbers
- `is_open` and `is_available` are strings

```
query.where(someRelationalPathBase.something.eq(someRelationalPathBase.somethingElse)
            .and(ce.id.stringValue().concat(ci.isOpen())
            .notIn(SQLExpressions.select(futClient.clientId.stringValue().concat(futClient.isAvailable))
            .from(futClient))));
```